# Kivy - Black Screen between transitions

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to copy this [gif](https://kivy.org/docs/_images/screenmanager.gif), which is done in Kivy (here's the [link](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html) to the full page )

Just as I started, I noticed a black screen between transition  ([link](http://makeagif.com/QSxAIQ) to what it looks like so you don't have to copy-paste and run)

Why does that black screen appear?

EDIT: I must work without buttons.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

# Create both screens. Please note the root.manager.current: this is how
# you can control the ScreenManager from kv. Each screen has by default a
# property manager that gives you the instance of the ScreenManager used.
Builder.load_string("""
    <MenuScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 122,255,0,2
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        text: 'hello'


<SettingsScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,255,0,2
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        text: 'hello'
""")

# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        sm.current = 'settings'

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        sm.current = 'menu'

# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

EDIT: I've tried this but still not working

```
<sm>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (0, 255, 255)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not supposed to use the Screen subclasses directly. Instead you must add a component first (e.g. Button or Layout), for example use `RelativeLayout`:

```
Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    RelativeLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 122,255,0,2
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Label:
            text: 'hello'


<SettingsScreen>:
    RelativeLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0,255,0,2
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Label:
            text: 'hello'
""")
```

Answer (score 1):

That black area is a canvas of the screen manager. If you don't like it black, then you can paint it, just like you did with screens; or change transition type to `NoTransition` to hide it.

Also, you should consider building your screen manager inside that kv lang string.

Comment: How do I exactly paint it ? 
This is my first Kivy project, so it is all new to me.

Comment: @SnuKies You have provided a code example where you painted some screens. Do the same to the screen manager.

Comment: @jiligeza I really can't. If you could, I ask you to provide the code. What I've tried is edited.
But it does now work. I'm stucked

Comment: @SnuKies You should take your time and learn kivy through coding tutorials and reading documentation. There is no other way around, but I can guarantee it's worth it.

Comment: But this black area doesn't show when using canvas.after, only with canvas.before.  There has to be a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Old, but in case anyone runs into this issue:

To clarify the vague responses in the comments, you need to paint your screen manager the same way you would paint a screen.

Example in kvlang:

```
ScreenManagement:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    id: screen_manager
    transition: NoTransition()
    Screen1:
    Screen2:
    Settings_:
```